# Newton form of the interpolation polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

Let $ f(x)=\sin(x) $ and let $ p_1 $ be the first degree polynomial that interpolates $ f $ at $0$ and $\pi/2$. Then $ p_1(x)=(2/pi)x. $

How did they get this result; how is $ p_1(x) $ found?

Comment: $f(0)=0$ and $f(\pi/2) = 1$. Take $p_1(x) = ax+b$ and solve $p_1(0) = 0$ and $p_1(\pi/2) = 1$

Comment: Having understood the above comment and the answer, I would add $f(\pi/4) = \sqrt{2}/2$ and try to find $p_2(x) = ax^2+bx+c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p_1(x)=ax+b$. We want $p_1(0)=f(0)=0$ and $p_1(\pi/2)=f(\pi/2)=1$. Thus, you get $0=b$, $1=a\pi/2+b=a\pi/2$, so $a=2/\pi$.

Comment: How do you get 0=b?

Comment: @user1961722: Evaluate $p_1(0)$...

Comment: But we're trying to find $ p_1(x) $, how can we use it?

Comment: @user1961722: if you are trying to figure out a degree $n$ polynomial you need $n+1$ equations. In your case the degree is 1, so you need 2 equations.

Comment: Okay thanks. Do you know what the general formula is to find a degree $ n $ interpolating polynomial?

Comment: @user1961722: you need $n+1$ different points. The general term for this is Lagrange Interpolation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial